# How to check if something has been process Python

Tags: python

I have to check if a string/email has been process
If it has been process is because "END" has been printed

The process I have is a loop with this structure every day checking 5 days before:

> Get email -> Process email -> Get info -> Modify Data --> "END"

I have to save this:

| Email | Processed? | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a@gmail.com | True | 08/04/2021 |
| b@gmail.com | False | 02/04/2021 |

I am thinking using a dictionary like this:

```
Keys: email, processed, date
Values: ['a@gmail.com','b@gmail.com'], [True, False], ['08/04/2021', '02/04/2021']
```

But I am not sure at all

What do you suggest me?

Comment: The proposed approach is counter intuitive and not scalable - simply ugly. The normal way would be a list of (3 keyed) dictionaries each corresponding to one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Anandha's answer a step further, I'd do it like:

```
data = {'a@gmail.com' : {"processed":True,'date':'08/04/2021'}, 'b@gmail.com' : {"processed":False,'date':'02/04/2021'}}
```

Which would then have a full status report as:

```
for key in data:
    if data[key]['processed'] not True:
        print("We have not yet processed account: " + key)         
    else:
        print(key + " was processed on " + data[key]['date'])
```

or if you wanted to check an individual

```
key = "a@gmail.com"
if data[key]['processed'] not True:
        print("We have not yet processed account: " + key)         
    else:
        print(key + " was processed on " + data[key]['date'])
```

Obviously, you'd put the if loop into a separate function to tidy up your code.

In terms of searching 5 days before, I'd recommend converting your date entries using datetime.strptime() and then timedelta(days=-5) from datetime.now() to check whether its within the 5 day window.

edit: To create the dict (single entry):

```
data = {}
data['c@gmail.com']={'processed':False, 'date':'2021/04/08'}
data['d@gmail.com']={'processed':True, 'date':'2021/04/07'}
```

If you are creating from an existing file or variable, then I'd need to see the shape of it before making recommendations.

Comment: Dont worry for the time, it is just to get it, i dont really use it at all. My question now is , do I use a list of dictionaries or a unique dictionary with email key??

Comment: From experience, when you can use a dictionary, do so. It makes both indexing and later modification much easier as its far more flexible.

Comment: I dont know how  can I create this dictionary you gave me, but using varibles instead strings.
For a@gmail.com the variable is the header 'email' and this is the key in your data dictionary, and the values are the other headers
I just dont know how to code that

Comment: Added an edit for adding lines to the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that's how I know, but I have to used the variables: email, processed and date
Because the strings I wrote , I dont know it, it is just and examples

data = {}
data[email] = {processed : '',  date: ''}

Comment: To be clear, "processed" and "date" are strings called "processed" and "date", they are NOT variables. Your line would be data[<email>] = {"processed":<processed>, "date":<date>}. Where <> is denoting a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON made as list of objects (this is a [valid JSON](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/?process=true&data=%5B%7B%22email%22:%22foo@example.com%22,%22processed%22:true,%22date%22:%222021-04-08%22%7D,%7B%22email%22:%22bar@example.com%22,%22processed%22:false,%22date%22:%222021-04-06%22%7D%5D#))

```json
[
   {
      "email":"foo@example.com",
      "processed":true,
      "date":"2021-04-08"
   },
   {
      "email":"bar@example.com",
      "processed":false,
      "date":"2021-04-06"
   }
]
```

The corrispondencies with Python objects (`list` and `dict`) is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the dictionary you suggested works well but in the event, you are scaling this up to several thousands of emails it will be a bit difficult for you to retrieve this data. If you have a million emails and you want to check if abc@gmail.com is processed or not, you will have to find the index of the email and then use the index.

I would suggest using the email as the key for something like this

```
{'a@gmail.com' : [True,'08/04/2021'], 'b@gmail.com' : [False,'02/04/2021']}
```

Such that even if you have a million emails you can get all the details using `dictionary['a@gmail.com']`